# How to shift values through the keys of an array-like object?

Tags: javascript

For an `array` I can do:

```
array.push(array.shift())
```

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array.push(array.shift())

console.log(array); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
```

How can I do the same for an `object`?

**Input**

```
var object = {0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'BMW', 3: 'Citroën'}
```

How can I move `{0: 'Fiat'}` to the end of the `object`

**Expected output:**

```
{0: 'Audi', 1: 'BMW', 2: 'Citroën', 3: 'Fiat'}
```

Comment: I dont want to sort the JavaScript object by key.

Comment: The answer is the same, though: "JavaScript objects1 are not ordered. It is meaningless to try to "sort" them".

Comment: You want to sort it, the point is there is no order in an object

Comment: @LazarLjubenović , Pablo, the question and its answer don't provide any kind of order or sorting.

Comment: "Move to end" _is_ an order.

Comment: I've retracted my vote: I think the question should be re-phrased, but I see it as a valid question: How to shift values through the keys of an array-like object?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović What exactly makes an order? When you literally write an object in a certain order, in the memory it is presented differently. Only what matters is the case, when we're iterating through the object, then we need an "order". In OP's case iterating the object with a regular `for` loop (not with `for..in`) gives the correct order despite of the order in the memory. Hence the goal can be achieved by simply renaming the properties. But as you've stated in a comment, an array should have been used from the beginning.

Comment: I rename the title as suggested @PabloLozano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following way

```js
var object = {0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'BMW', 3: 'Citroën'};

var result = Object.keys(object).map(e => object[e]);
//console.log(result);

result.push(result.shift());
//console.log(result);

let ans = Object.assign({}, result);
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Im going to try this. Sounds logical to convert it to an array. My object holds  jQuery elements. So idk if that works. Ill let you know.

Comment: the question is, why does it work that way, mapping just the items?

Comment: You should just work with an Array from the start, instead of an array-like object.

Comment: The actual object looks completly different. But I did convert it to an array now, with the help of your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert you object with the given keys as index to an array, apply the shifting and convert back to an object.

```js
var object = { 0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 4: 'BMW', 5: 'Citroën' },
    array = Object.keys(object).reduce((r, k, i) => (r[i] = object[k], r), []);

array.push(array.shift());

console.log(Object.assign({}, array)); // { 0: "Audi", 1: "BMW", 2: "Citroën", 3: "Fiat" }
```

A different approach, while respecting the keys.

```js
var object = { 0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 4: 'BMW', 5: 'Citroën' },
    keys = Object.keys(object);
    result = Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: object[keys[(i + 1) % keys.length]] })));

console.log(result); // { 0: "Audi", 1: "BMW", 4: "Citroën", 5: "Fiat" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The object's properties does not have any guarantee on the order, in which they may appear, concise there is no concept as order. I think you need to think more and can find another solution, which does not depend on the properties order.

Comment: That means its not possible for objects?

Comment: You can delete your property and add it under the last properties number + 1, but rest properties you need to also change. Try to find a solution with array, as your object is more like to an array

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your object into an array, do the reordering on the array and convert the array back to an object:

```js
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}

function toArray(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) { return object[key]; });
}


var object = {0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'BMW', 3: 'Citroën'}
var array = toArray(object);
array.push(array.shift());
object = toObject(array);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on ordering of object's keys in JavaScript. It's not defined by standard. Objects by definition do not have an ordering, so there is **no "end" of the object**. It simply doesn't make sense to "move" a key of an object anywhere, since there's no ordering.

The data-structure which *does* have orders are arrays.

Your object is *almost* array-like, because all of its keys are consecutive numbers, but it's missing a `lenght` property. With `length`, you could turn it into an actual array with `Array.from(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Teaching: Objects are usually based on a [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for lookup by key.
As a consequence this usually means you do not have order.

```
myObj[key] => find value by computing hash of key => returns value
```

Answer (score 0):

As Suren said, the object does not guarantee the insertion order. I suggest another approach for example:

```
const o = {0: 'Fiat', 1: 'Audi', 2: 'BMW', 3: 'Citroën'};
const k = Object.keys(o);
k.push(k.shift());
const result = k.map((v, i) => ({[i]: o[v]}))
   .reduce((acum, v) => Object.assign(acum, v), {});
```

The approach here is to create and index array, apply the logic (push and shift) then re-build the object with map, and then merge them into one object with reduce. I think this could be shorter (just the reduce) but i wanted to split this up to be more clear.